# Please Explain Java 8 Method Reference to instance Method using class name

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference, functional-interface

```
public interface MyFunc<T> {

    boolean func(T v1, T v2);

}
```

```
public class HighTemp {

    private int hTemp;

    HighTemp(){

    }
    public HighTemp(int ht) {
        this.hTemp = ht;
    }

    boolean sameTemp(HighTemp ht2){
         return hTemp == ht2.hTemp;
    }

     boolean lessThanTemp(HighTemp ht2){
        return hTemp < ht2.hTemp;
    }
}
```

```
class InstMethWithObjRef {

    static <T> int counter(T[] vals, MyFunc<T> f, T v){
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
            if(f.func(vals[i], v)) count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count;
        //Create an array of HighTemp objects.
        HighTemp[] weekDayHighs = {new HighTemp(89), new HighTemp(82),
                                   new HighTemp(90), new HighTemp(89),
                                   new HighTemp(89), new HighTemp(91),
                                   new HighTemp(84), new HighTemp(83)};
        count = counter(weekDayHighs, HighTemp::lessThanTemp,new HighTemp(89));     
        System.out.println(count);          
    }
}
```

Please explain how

1. `boolean sameTemp()` is compatible with `func()` in Functional interface.
2. `sameTemp()` method got implemented on `func()` in Functional Interface.
3. `count = counter(weekDayHighs, HighTemp::sameTemp, new HighTemp(89));` is working

Please Explain All points separately.

Comment: This code works fine but i don't understand how sameTemp() is compatible with func(), when func() has two parameter and sameTemp() has one.

Comment: comment me if you don't understand my question

Comment: Are you sure the code works? `hTemp` is declared as `static` so every time you construct `HighTemp` the value changes for all the instances, which would result in `count` being always 0.

Comment: sorry about that i removed the static from hTemp. It was add by mistake

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Equivalent* lambda expression of `HighTemp::lessThanTemp` is

```
(highTemp1, highTemp2) -> {
     return highTemp1.lessThanTemp(highTemp2);
}
```

This is one of the features of `Java8` named [*Reference to an Instance Method of an Arbitrary Object of a Particular Type*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

---

Consider following example,

```
interface FIface<T> {
    int testMethod(T a, T b);
}

class Test2 {

    private String str;

    Test2(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    int ok(Test2 test2) {
        System.out.println("Currnet String : "+ this.str);//Refer to t1
        System.out.println("Test String : "+test2.str);//Refer to t2
        return 0;
    }

}

public class Test {

    public static <T> int checkCall(T t1, T t2, FIface<T> fiFace) {
        //Here Test2 :: ok is equivalent to t1.ok(t2)
        return fiFace.testMethod(t1, t2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        checkCall(new Test2("a"), new Test2("b"), Test2 :: ok);
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Currnet String : a
Test String : b
```

Note here that `Test2 :: ok` is valid for the call even `ok` method is not static.

When you call the method `checkCall` for the functional interface you still have two arguments which are `t1` and `t2` and for that valid lambda expression can have parameters as `(Test t1, Test t2)` so your method `Test2 :: ok` here becomes valid for the call. Internally it works this way `t1.ok(t2)`.

So, `fiFace.testMethod(t1, t2);` will will invoke method as `t1.ok(t2)`

Comment: Sir, can you explain me with an example of using sub signature in a small program similar to mine. So that i can easily understand, Thanks

Comment: Add comments in program for explanation. That's would be great.

Answer (score 3):

For starters I'm not a professional programmer. I too had a great difficulty in understanding the so called "***Reference to an Instance Method of an Arbitrary Object of a Particular Type***" I think this might be helpful for somebody who comes here from a google search.
I understood it a little bit with the help of lambda expressions.
In your code `HighTemp::lessThanTemp` as a Lambda expression would look like `(x,y)->{x.lessThanTemp(y);}` Replacing the method reference with this lambda expression would produce the same result. The above Lambda expression or the method reference both tell the interface method what to do. 
When you use the method reference it tells the interface method to use the referred method from the given class, to carryout its function. Therefore if you convert `HighTemp::lessThanTemp` to English words it would sound something like "*implement the `lessThanTemp` method form the class `HighTemp` as the implementation of the interface function*". As you might've noticed in that case the return types and the argument types should be compatible. Otherwise you cannot implement an interface.
 
I would provide you another simple example code. More examples helps to understand this concept.

```
interface myint{
    int returnit(Test t ,int y);
}
class Test{
    int x=0;
    public Test(int x){
        this.x=x;
    }

    public int addNumbers(int y){
        return x+y;
    }
    public int subtractNumbers(int y){
        return x-y;
    }

}

public class myclass{
    private static void myMethod(Test t,myint inf,int y){
        int x=inf.returnit(t, y);
        System.out.println(x+"");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        myMethod(new Test(4),Test::addNumbers,7);
        myMethod(new Test(4),Test::subtractNumbers,7);
    }
}
```

Output would be:

```
11
-3
```

This is the simplest way I could imagine it. See how return types and argument types gets matched using the above sentence pattern. Spend some time on it.

Comment: +1 NICE Answer but i have a doubt , you Told arguments and return types should be matched what about access Specifier ? should that also be matched ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the Interface

```
package learninglambdaexp;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface TempInterface {

    public boolean validTemp(Temperature temp);
}
```

This is the class

```
package learninglambdaexp;

public class Temperature {

    private int temp;

    public Temperature(int temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    public boolean isEvenTemp() {
        return temp % 2 == 0;
    }

    public boolean isOddTemp(){
    return !isEvenTemp();
    }
}
```

This is the Class with the Main Method

```
package learninglambdaexp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AnotherMainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Temperature> tempCollection = new ArrayList<>();
        tempCollection.add(new Temperature(100));
        tempCollection.add(new Temperature(20));
        tempCollection.add(new Temperature(30));
        tempCollection.add(new Temperature(40));
        tempCollection.add(new Temperature(50));
        tempCollection.add(new Temperature(60));
        tempCollection.add(new Temperature(70));
        int k1 = countVariation(tempCollection, Temperature::isEvenTemp);
        //int k2 = countVariation(Temperature::lowTemp);
        System.out.println(k1);
        // System.out.println(k2); 
    }

    private static int countVariation(List<Temperature> tempCollection, TempInterface ti) {
        int count = 0;
        for (Temperature eachTemp : tempCollection) {
            if (ti.validTemp(eachTemp)) { // (eachTemp) -> {return eachTemp.isEvenTemp();};
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

With one argument its easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

Please, correct me if I am wrong, but the way I think about this type of method references (**Reference to an Instance Method of an Arbitrary Object of a Particular Type**) is that when we pass a method reference, in this case to the *counter* method, the instance of anonymous class which implements *MyFunc* interface is created. Then, inside this anonymous class, we override *func* method which is passed two parameters. And then inside the *func* method, *lessThanTemp* method is called like this:

```
v1.lessThanTemp(v2);
```

---

So for me this concept looks something like this:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnonymousClass an = new AnonymousClass();
        System.out.println(an.apply(new SomeClass(3), 4));
    }
}
interface SomeInterface {
    int apply(SomeClass obj, int n);
}

class SomeClass {
    private int n;

    SomeClass(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    int add(int n) {
        return this.n + n;
    }
}
class AnonymousClass implements SomeInterface {

    @Override
    public int apply(SomeClass o, int n) {
        return o.add(n);
    }
}
```