# Is this a java BUG?

Tags: java

why the following code can pass compile phase and run correctly?

There are two points that I can't understand:
First,`mapToLong` method accept a functionalInterface like this

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ToLongFunction<T> {

    /**
     * Applies this function to the given argument.
     *
     * @param value the function argument
     * @return the function result
     */
    long applyAsLong(T value);
}
```

but the method `longValue` of class `Number` is `public abstract long longValue();`
Second, the method `longValue` is a abstract method, but it can be passed to the `mapToLong` method as a argument, why is that?

Here is the code:

```
package com.pay.screen;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainTest {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(1L);
        list.add(2L);
        long sum = list.stream().mapToLong(Number::longValue).sum();
        System.out.println(sum);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't it?

Comment: `Number::longValue` can be written as `l -> l.longValue()`. it is not an actual implementation you're passing but rather a "description" of what should be done with every element in the stream. Try passing `Long::longValue` you see that it works as well

Comment: Maybe also have a look at this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32283833/please-explain-java-8-method-reference-to-instance-method-using-class-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perfectly fine and working as specified.

In addition to what Andy already said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54233269/2513200):

Looking at the [JLS 15.13. Method Reference Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13) we can see that

`Number::longValue` matches the 3rd form, i.e. `ReferenceType :: [TypeArguments] Identifier`

Nothing here says that the method cannot be `abstract`. Now, this method is a `ToLongFunction<Number>`, which is completely sufficient for 
`mapToLong`, as Andy already explained.

But it even works if we assign it to a `ToLongFunction<Double>`:

```
ToLongFunction<Double> f = Number::longValue;
```

See [15.13.1. Compile-Time Declaration of a Method Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1)

> In the second search, if P1, ..., Pn is not empty and P1 is a subtype of ReferenceType, then the method reference expression is treated as if it were a method invocation expression with argument expressions of types P2, ..., Pn.[...]

`P1` is `Double`, which is a subtype of `Number`, so this is fine.

There is only one form where referring to an `abstract` method is not ok, and that is

> **It is a compile-time error if the method reference expression has the form super :: [TypeArguments] Identifier or TypeName . super :: [TypeArguments] Identifier, and the compile-time declaration is abstract.**

that is, you explicity requested to invoke a method from a supertype, but that supertype only has an abstract method that would match.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Javadoc of `mapToLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToLong-java.util.function.ToLongFunction-):

> ```
> LongStream mapToLong(ToLongFunction<? super T> mapper)
> ```

Since the stream is a `Stream<Long>`, `mapToLong` requires a `ToLongFunction<? super Long>`.

`Number::longValue` can be a `ToLongFunction<Number>`, i.e. something which takes a `Number` and returns a `long`. You can pass a `Long` to a `ToLongFunction<Number>`, because all `Long`s are also `Number`s. Hence `ToLongFunction<Number>` is also a `ToLongFunction<? super Long>`.

Hence it's fine.