# How to use method referencing for a private method in same class

Tags: java, java-8

```
    public class Demo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Demo().pqr();
  }
   void pqr() {
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    l.add("abc");
    l.add("jkl");
    l.forEach(p -> print(p));
  }
  private void print(String l) {
    System.out.println(l);
  }
}
```

In above code how to replace lambda expression with method referencing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Please Explain Java 8 Method Reference to instance Method using class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32283833/please-explain-java-8-method-reference-to-instance-method-using-class-name)

Answer (score 1):

You can call by

```
 l.forEach(this::print);
```

Furthermore, explicit type argument String can be replaced with <>.

---

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
```

by

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution would be

```
l.forEach(this::print);
```